# Aggregating across collections

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've inherited a mongo schema which is currently quite strange to me as it contains many collections which I believe could easily be consolidated and in the process could increase the use of the aggregation/MapReduce features of Mongo.

The basic setup is as follows:

12+ collections. All collections have ids that could be compared across collections such as userId, sessionId, and appId. The collections are currently separated based on categorical data and customizable attributes within each collection in an analytics event context. One of the key collections consists of a general user profile that is updated based on parameters passed into the other collections.

I frequently have to aggregate values across collections to look at details such as user sessions since login, time since last session, time since first session, how active a user is across apps, how long has it been since a user performed a specific event? etc. All of which involves aggregating across the many event collections and the user collection.

I have not found an adequate means of "joining" user_ids across collections at scale. Any advice on restructuring the schema or on aggregation functions to make this faster would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, it is not possible to execute aggregate pipeline on multiple collections. So you have to do it in multiple operations, and you take each results, put that in a collection and execute another aggregate/query on this "working collection".

In 2.2 and 2.4 you have to do this work manually in your application code, but it 2.6 you can do it in the agregation itself.

In MongoDB 2.6 a new operator "**$out**" has been added to the aggregation framework to help you doing such operation. You can find information about this operator here : http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/